# Android Studio Not Detecting Device And ADB Interface With The Yellow Triangle

Tags: android, android-studio

I am an Android developer. Since yesterday, I flashed my phone and installed Cynogenmod.

In device manger, ADB interface has yellow triangle, and when I try to update it, it says ***no update file found***. I have installed all the drivers but still I am facing this problem.

Comment: So you have flashed cynogenmod on a device, and this device when connected to your computer isn't being detected by the adb running on your computer is that correct?

Comment: yep but it's connected the computer but adb is not showing it up. and even adb is detecting other devices

Comment: and i am using moto g3

Comment: so you've enabled developer options and usb debugging mode and granted this computer access?

Comment: yep it was working fine .. but  i am facing this issue since i installed the mod!!

Comment: do i have to grant permission even after installing the mod?

Comment: yes once you flash a new OS all your configuration is reset, so you need to re enable developer options and usb debugging mode and grant access to your computer

Comment: how can i do that now?? and i just tried to reinstall adb using adb installer it says [Failed] x64 Adb Driver install. i have connected my device and the driver status says Driver incorrectly

Comment: why are you trying to modify software on your computer? Goto settings in your mobile phone, check if you have developer options enabled, if you do check if you have usb debuggin enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105428/discussion-between-jois-and-bhargav).

Comment: @Unheilig: re your edit, just so you know: sentence case is preferred here for titles. Thanks!